# Why did oracle scheduler job execute old pl/sql code instead of modified pl/sql code

Tags: oracle

I have an existing Oracle scheduler job that runs once a day. The job purges old data from a database table calling a `pl/sql` stored procedure.

Example of `pl/sql`:

```
BEGIN mySchema.myPackage.purgeMyData(sysdate - 30); END;
```

This job runs fine at the designated scheduled day/time. However, we needed to change the parameter in the procedure call so that we'd only keep `15` days of data instead of `30` days.

So we modified the job's `pl/sql` to this:

```
BEGIN mySchema.myPackage.purgeMyData(sysdate - 15); END;
```

The job ran successfully last night, but it used the old `sysdate - 30` parameter instead of `sysdate - 15`. I reviewed the job and it is showing the `sysdate - 15` for the parameter.

Does anyone know why this happened and whether it will run correctly tonight? I'm wondering if the scheduler had it stored somewhere for the next schedule job run that didn't get updated. I searched the web and this site and couldn't find anything in regards to this. Any assistance would be appreciated.

I used SQL Developer to update the job by right clicking on the job and selecting `edit`, changing the parameter in `pl/sql`, and clicking `apply`.

Comment: I didn't change the PL/SQL procedure that gets called. I just changed the parameter value that gets used in the call to the stored procedure. The procedure is already compiled and working. Job executed fine last night, just used the old parameter value instead of the new one.

Comment: Woops, looks like I could have read your question better ! I don't know the first thing about Oracle Scheduler so I won't be able to help you, sorry.